# Google Pixel Bootloader unlock

Tags: boot-loop, fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock, google-pixel

I have a pixel phone struck in boot loop (just show google logo and restarts)!

I didnt enable oem unlock and usb debugging !

I want to unlock the phone to reflash the phone!

My Recovery also dont work! just stuck at google logo!

I have tried all the google search but there is no direct answer for this!

most of the fastboot command errors comes like this

```
FAILED (remote: 'oem unlock is not allowed')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

Please help as I cannot buy new phone now

Thanks,
Sharan

Comment: How did you manage to crash the recovery without unlocking the device?

Comment: I bought this phone from ebay